# Clang++ compiler - analog for python

Tags: c++, python, clang, clang++

is there a similar alternative updated and working compiler for python like clang for c++?

I find error messages unclear sometimes.

Comment: Do you definitely mean a compiler? Python is usually implemented as an intepreted language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What exactly are you trying to do?

C and C++ are **compiled** languages, that's why there are several compilers for them like CLANG. However Python is an interpreted language, it can not be compiled in a way as a C/C++ code can.

Technically, they are *compiled* to byte-code, but it's done automatically when you run your script, for example: `python my_script.py` -- it will create or update a `my_script.pyc` file and then the interpreter will run this *compiled* version.

There are several tools to create a shared library of your code (with [**cython**](http://cython.org/) for example) or to use your code with a Just-In-Time compiler (with [**pypy**](http://pypy.org/)) if those are the things you are looking for.

Comment: in addition to pypy, there is also jython and ironpython, but except where they produce the same exception messages, cpython usually gives better feedback about errors (it has teaching as a design goal)

Comment: Language cannot be "compiled" or "interpreted". Python can be compiled, although it is not easy to compile it into an *efficient* code.